# How can I search for a user based on a Certificate in LDAP?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, certificate

How do I search for a specific user object in LDAP that has an associated x509 certificate? Do I need to encode it in a certain way? It looks like the attribute is userCertificate based on looking at JXplorer.

Note: Accessing Active Directory through LDAP

Answer (score 1):

This is usually accomplished by associating the certificate DN with the LDAP entry.

Comment: but, how do I search for it with java? Do I submit the byte array using userCertificate={0} or do I encode it to a string somehow

Comment: Also, how are multiple certificates handled - so is the '=' the correct operator to use?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may depend on your server providing LDAP and the syntax of the userCertificate attribute.  It might be a string attribute then the contents would need to be base 64 encoded.  Or else it might an octet syntax attribute.

By search 'using' a certificate, what do you mean?  Connect over SSL/TLS with a cert, or find an object that has this specific certificate assigned to them?   Not clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, but looking for this specifically: "find an object that has this specific certificate assigned to them"

Comment: Does your LDAP server store the Certificate Private Key, or a DN referencing a certificate object, or what?  That seems to get you to the crux of the question.